# How to display all X Values on chart without using ChartArea ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I'm working on the analyze part of my project and i need to display some values from the database on a chart.
my method worked perfectly and the chart is displayed correctly but some of the X-VALUES are missing like it is shown in the picture : 
[The Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FePXi.png)

here is the code of the interface that will show the modal that will display the chart

```
@using System.Data
@model DataTable
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListQuestionnaire";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layoutadmin.cshtml";
}

<style>
    .btn {
        background-color: DodgerBlue; /* Blue background */
        border: none; /* Remove borders */
        color: white; /* White text */
        padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
        font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
        cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
    }

        /* Darker background on mouse-over */
        .btn:hover {
            background-color: RoyalBlue;
        }
</style>
<script>
    function analyse(id) {
         $.ajax({
                       url: '@Url.Action("Charts", "Dashboard")',
                       data: { idq : id },
                        type: 'post',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                         //   $("#dash").prop("src", "@Url.Action("MyChart")");
                             $('.contents').html(response);
                        $('#type').modal('show');
                         },
                       error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                           alert('Error encountered while saving' + status);
        }
                   });
    }
</script>

<h2 style="margin-top:30px; margin-bottom : 50px;"> Liste Des Questionnaires</h2>
<div class="table-responsive-sm" style="height:300px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {
                <tr id="norme">
                    <td style="width:35%;">@row["titre"]</td>
                    <td style="width:35%;">
                        Score Total : @row["score_total"]
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn" id="supp" onclick="analyse(@row["id_quest"]);"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i> Analyser</button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="type" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:700px; overflow-x:scroll">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Analyse</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body contents" >

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The is the method that the button "Analyse" call :

```
 [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Charts(string idq)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select poid , id_cond from Conditions where id_quest=@id ", con);
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(idq));
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt1.Load(dr);
                }
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select poid , score,id_cond from Actions  ", con);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt2.Load(dr);
                }
                con.Close();
                int x = dt1.Rows.Count;
                int[]poid = new int[x];
                int i = 0;
                int[]pdc = new int[x];
                int c = 0;
                TempData["taille"] = x;
                foreach (DataRow r1 in dt1.Rows)
                {
                    pdc[c] = int.Parse(r1["poid"].ToString());
                    int id = int.Parse(r1["id_cond"].ToString());
                    foreach (DataRow r2 in dt2.Rows)
                    {
                        if (r1["id_cond"].ToString() == r2["id_cond"].ToString())
                        {
                            if (r2["score"].ToString() == "True")
                            {
                                int pd = int.Parse(r2["poid"].ToString());
                                poid[i] = poid[i] + pd;
                            }
                            else
                                poid[i] = poid[i] + 0;
                        }
                    }
                    c++;
                    i++;
                }
                TempData["poid"] = poid;
                TempData["cond"] = pdc;
                return PartialView("~/views/Dashboard/Charts.cshtml");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Problems, " + ex.Message.ToString() + " line : " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                return RedirectToAction("ListQuestionsAdmin");
            }
        }
```

The PartialView only has one line :

```
<img src="@Url.Action("MyChart")" alt="Line-Chart" width="700px" height="250px" />
```

and finally, the method to create the chart :

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult MyChart ()
        {
            int x = int.Parse(TempData.Peek("taille").ToString());
            int[] poid = new int[x];
            int[] cond = new int[x];
            poid = TempData["poid"] as int[];
            cond = TempData["cond"] as int[];
             string[] poidc = new string[x];
            int j = 1;

            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                poidc[i]= "C-" + j +" : "+ cond[i] + "%";
                j++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" x value : " + poidc[i]);
            }
       new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 1000, height: 300).AddSeries(

                chartType: "column",
                xValue: poidc,
                yValues: poid
                ).Write("png");
            return null;


        }
```

Like You noticed from the code I'm not using a chartArea so the solution About "ChartArea.Axis.Interval = 1" won't work for me.
Is there any other way to display all the X-Values?

Comment: Yo are adding the x-values as `strings`. This is usually a mistake as this will lose the values (although the values get copied to the lables.). Add them as numbers; `double` is the internal type.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work because there are repeated values(for exp i have three conditions with value = 10 ) so it only displayed 4 values while i need all the values to be displayed even repeated.

Comment: Then additionally make the Series [indexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: that work while using **System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting** while i'm using **System.Web.Helpers**

Comment: So you are not using an MSChart? Then I am out of it..